# How do I extract particular data from a large table which hasn't been normalized?

Tags: excel, database, database-design, data-cleaning

The original table in excel looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3T6A.png). It has around 30000 records. I want to copy a particular value for each record given by their unique FPS ID (which is a primary key). However, with an unclean data like this I can't put my finger on how to approach a problem like this. I want the data pulled from this table to be arranged like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RknyM.png).

Basically what I want here is the figure highlighted by grey.
There are two of those, I only want the one without the address but this doesn't have the primary key.

Approach 1: Select and filter them to a new sheet and manually adjust for redundant data

Approach 2:  Select and filter them to a new sheet, this time however, strip the contents of the cell to just have the primary key enclosed within parenthesis.

How should I go about this? I am very weak at VLOOKUP, VBA etc.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please show what you are able to do & results of your research. What exactly are you trying to accomplish & how exactly are you stuck? [mre] [ask] [help]

Comment: If you have no control over the format of the original table, I suggest you develop a VBA solution to effect the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VLOOKUP will be helpful in here. I think you should do it this way:

First of all look at the sequence. Rice totals are located in "B8", "B14", "B20"... +6

FPS names in cells "A9", "A15", "A21"... +6

FPS IDs in cells "A4", "A10", "A16"... +6

You can use cell references for rice totals by typing =B8, then under it =B14 an so on. But it will take you a lot of time. You can use this trick: Type B8, and under it B14. Select them both and drag down until the end of the data.Then select them all, press Ctrl + H. In the 1st field type in B. In the 2nd field type in =B and press "Replace All". It will activate the formula.

Answer (score 0):

1: Learn about the difference between a spreadsheet and an RDBMS.

2: Design an RDBMS schema that meets your needs. (You can use SQL Server Express)

3: Copy the data that you need into the RDBMS.

4: Write SQL Queries to extract the data that you need.

5: Put a big reminder notice on your office wall:

"I must not use spreadsheets for database work".